# My Computer enters grub recovery mode everytime when booting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, windows-10-upgrade

So, this problem has been around ever since I made a **new update to my Windows 10**. I have a **dual system on my PC (Windows 10 and Ubuntu)** and I can't figure out why I **enter grub rescue mode everytime when I boot my computer**. I have found solutions concerning getting into normal mode by using **ls,set,etc.. commands**, but it's getting annoying to repeat this process everytime when I turn on my computer.

Did anyone have a simmilar problem?
Is there a problem with my grub? What steps should I follow in order to get rid of that annoying grub recovery mode window when booting my PC?

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

Get into grub

find linux

```
grub rescue> ls
```

find /boot

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt8)/boot
```

set parameters

```
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,gpt8)
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub
```

make normal boot

```
grub rescue> insmod normal
grub rescue> normal
```

You can then finish Windows 10 upgrade.

After Windows 10 upgrade finishes successfully, we want to fix grub. Do these steps after you get into Linux system (Debian 8)

```
# mkdir /boot/efi
# mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi
```

if grub-efi-amd64 exists run

```
# apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
```

if grub-efi-amd64 does not exist run

```
# aptitude install grub-efi-amd64

# grub-install /dev/sda
# update-grub
# mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/boot
# cp /boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
```

http://garasiku.web.id/web/joomla/index.php/debian/46-how-to-fix-grub-efi-debian-8-after-windows-10-upgrade